# Custom loss with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, lambda

I have two layer outputs and need to compare both and also there is an MSE between prediction and ground truth.

So I added it like this:

```
losses = lambda y_true, y_pred: tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) + \
tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error(layer1_output, layer2_output)
```

But there is an error:

```
TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_16'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

How to add two different custom loss properly?
Thanks,

Comment: If we define custom loss function that combines both the mean squared error (MSE) between prediction and ground truth and the MSE between two layer outputs. Kindly refer this git code [link](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/LavanyaKV1234/355b0a2b5a1f8c55f7ce0c75460b9a21/tensorflow.ipynb#scrollTo=ZwhnsN0ttg5Q).